# How to cast a null date in an hibernate nativeQuery?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, date, casting, null

I'm using postgreSQL and hibernate. Because I've to use SQL queries that is not take into account by hibernate, I use nativeQuery in my Query annotation.
I have multiple dates param and inevitably at least two of them are null.

I have to check a condition only if my param isn't null. The problem is that I'm not able to cast my date if this one is null.

I try different possible solutions but nothing works

- `:dEchTransacEqual is null OR transaction.d_ech_transac = cast(:dEchTransacEqual as date)`
- `coalesce(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual, null) is null OR transaction.d_ech_transac >= cast(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual as date)`
- `CASE cast(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual as date) WHEN not null THEN transaction.d_ech_transac >= cast(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual as date) END`
- `CASE coalesce(cast(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual as boolean), null) WHEN not null THEN transaction.d_ech_transac >= cast(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual as date) END`
- `to_date(cast(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual as date), 'YYYY/MM/DD') is null OR transaction.d_ech_transac >= cast(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual as date)`
- `:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual is null OR transaction.d_ech_transac >=  to_date(cast(:dEchTransacGreaterThanEqual as date), 'YYYY/MM/DD')`

I don't have more idea to solve my problem.
How can I handle the nullity of my date using the nativeQuery of hibernate?

The last (and dirty) solution is to implement as many repo method as I have use cases (3).

PS. : I have to use nativeQuery because I'm using over() and partition by that isn't handle by Hibernate.

Comment: I finally split my query into two. The first one in JPQL which handle dates and the second one (which take the first one's output as parameter) in charge of the analytics functions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PG does not support "IS NULL" test for parameters. It means that you must build a query dynamically. If you don't want manipulate strings, you may use FluentJPA's [Dynamic Queries](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Dynamic-Queries), which also supports [`OVER` clause](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Window-Functions).